# Wrap a div around Woocommerce elements

Tags: php, woocommerce, word-wrap

I'm designing my first Woocommerce store, but i've found a bit of a hassle.

What i want is the product title, sale span & images on the left and additional info on the right.

The problem is there are no divs wrapped around the three elements.
Also there is no div wrapped around all these info.

Is there any way to write a hook for this in the functions.php?

I already use this one to move the title to the top of the page:

```
/*---Move Product Title*/
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can wrap around the php includes in the template file. `content-single-product.php`. Make sure template overrides are in your theme folder under a folder named woocommerce